# What cause that type mismatch with underlying type in Scala

Tags: scala, class, types, traits

I have the following code:

```
trait M[A] {
  def unit(a: A): M[A]
  def ★[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}

case class State[A, S](run: S => (A, S)) extends M[A] {
  def unit[S](a: A): M[A] = State((s: S) => (a, s))
  def ★[B, S](f: A => M[B]): M[B] = State((s0: S) => {
    val (a, s1) = this.run(s0)
    val (b, s2) = f(a)(s1)
    (b, s2)
  })
}
```

but I get:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : s0.type (with underlying type S)
 required: S
    val (a, s1) = this.run(s0)
                           ^
error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: A
    val (b, s2) = f(a)(s1)
                    ^
error: type mismatch;
 found   : b.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: B
    (b, s2)
     ^
three errors found
```

Does it means that I cannot mix abstract type A, B, S and case class instances in the definition of unit and ★ and that I should use a `trait State[A] extends M[A] {...}` instead ?

Comment: Type parameter `S` in `def unit[S]()` isn't the same `S` in `case class State[A, S]()`.  Neither is the `S` in `def *[B, S]()`.

Comment: @LeoC Yes, indeed, I can delete S in unit[S] and ★[B, S] they are not necessary but I get another errors.

Answer (score 3):

This example could be forced to be compilable (see part 2), but instead of doing so, I believe it's more valuable to compare it to the standard approach with typeclasses, and understand why attempting to fix this approach results in so much trouble.

## Comparison with the standard approach

Recall that modeling the state-monad with typeclasses would look somewhat like this:

```
trait Monad[F[_]]:
  def pure[A](a: => A): F[A]
  def flatMap[A, B](a: F[A], f: A => F[B]): F[B]

case class State[S, A](run: S => (S, A)):
  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(s0 =>
    val (s1, a) = this.run(s0)                                                           
    f(a).run(s1)                                              
  )

object State:
  given stateMonad[S]: Monad[[X] =>> State[S, X]] with
    def pure[A](a: => A): State[S, A] = State(s => (s, a))
    def flatMap[A, B](a: State[S, A], f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] =
      a.flatMap(f)
```

Note that there are three distinct parts here:

- `Monad[F]`-typeclass, which basically corresponds to the statement "`F` is a monad", parameterized by `F`
- The `State`, a separate data structure *about which* we are making statements
- The `implicit`/`given` `stateMonad`, which is a constructive proof of the statement "for all `S`, `[X] => State[S, X]` is a monad".

Note that the `Monad` part (the statement) is strictly separate from the `F` part (the object about which we are making the statement).

Taken together, these three parts can be described by natural language roughly as follows:

> "There is a data structure `State`. It is a `Monad`. Here is the proof: ..."

Now compare this to the formulation with `extends` from the question:

```
trait M[A] {
  def unit(a: A): M[A]
  def ★[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}

case class State[A, S](run: S => (A, S)) extends M[A] { ... }
```

Here, the *statement* "something is a monad" is supposed to be extended by "something" that it itself attempts to describe. The `M` is both the statement that the "something" has such-and-such methods (`unit`, `*`), but it's also the thing that is being described. Translated into natural language prose, this formulation corresponds roughly to the unwieldy

> "`M` states that it itself will be extended by something that has certain methods (`unit`, `*` etc.), whose definitions refer to the extending thing itself."

which is a special case of

> "`M` states that it will be extended by some `S`, and that the `S` will satisfy some properties that refer to `S` (and thus also to `M`)"

which is a special case of

> "`M` states that `M` has some properties"

which is a known recipe for creating all kinds of self-referential cyclical statements such as

> "`M` states that `M` is false."

better known as the Liar's paradoxon

> "This statement is false."

So, the emergence of F-bounded polymorphism and the explosion of all those invalid cyclic-reference errors is not accidental: by attempting to merge the thing that is being described with the statement that does the describing, you're creating this proto-paradoxical self-referential structure.

Therefore, I'd suggest to stick to the standard formulation, and keep the statements separate from the things about which one wants to make the statements.

---

## How one could force it to compile

*(All of the following is purely for educational purposes, I would not suggest to use the resulting code; It serves only as an example for demonstrating several interesting compilation errors; Long story short: don't attempt to use F-bounded polymorphism to define monad interfaces, use typeclasses instead)*

The `extends M[A]` is a red flag. Theoretically, you can make it work, but it won't be pretty.

Several problems here:

1. You are binding `S` twice, so that the `S` in the `State[A, S]` is shadowed by the non-inferable `S` from `unit[S]`, so that nothing fits together. This can be solved by eliminating some of the unnecessary `S`-s.
2. The `A` in `unit` seems to depend in an unexpected way on the type bound by `State[A, S]`. It would be better if it had its own `A`.
3. Even if you fix this, you immediately run into problem that the return types in the methods of your `M` are way too vague: you don't want just anything that implements `M` in some way, you want the same type that is implementing `M`. This can be solved by F-bounded polymorphism, but this leads you to an even worse problem that...
4. ...You need type-lambdas to express the F-bounded polymorphism. This gets outright ugly without kind-projector or first-class type lambda support.
5. There are multiple things that are unconventional: `unit` is usually called `pure`, the order of parameters is usually `State[S, A]`, because the second parameter plays better with type inference.

Combining Scala 3's type lambda support with inexplicable amounts of unprovoked disproportionate violence, we thus obtain:

```
trait M[F[X] <: M[F, X], A] {
  def unit[A](a: A): F[A]
  def ★[B](f: A => F[B]): F[B]
}

case class State[S, A](run: S => (A, S)) extends M[[X] =>> State[S, X], A] {
  def unit[A](a: A): State[S, A] = State((s: S) => (a, s))
  def ★[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State((s0: S) => {
    val (a, s1) = this.run(s0)
    val (b, s2) = f(a).run(s1)
    (b, s2)
  })
}
```

...which compiles, but is very awkward to use, because it requires an instance of a correctly typed `State` just in order to invoke `unit`, which defeats the purpose.

It's a good exercise, but the resulting code is highly suboptimal. There are good use cases for mixing monads with `extends`, but this is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you for that long reply. For the fisrt point, yes I can delete S in unit[S] and in ★[B, S] which avoid those errors but I get another one where the method run is not a member of M[B]. If I simply change M[B] by State[S, B] then I am no more implementing methods from the trait M[A]. So F-bounded polymorphism seems the solution, but is M[F[X] <: M[F, X], A] still works for single type and not only State[S, A]  ?

Comment: @Shodz I don't understand your last sentence, could you please try to reformulate it?

Comment: Yes of course. I mean the constraint on upper-bound does not allows to use class with a single type like ```class BoxMonad[A](box: A)``` so M[F[A], A] can be used to be more general I think. Also, on scala 2 the type-lambda ```M[({type λ[A]=State[S, A]})#λ, A]``` does not work, I get a cyclic reference, it's curious it works in scala 3. Concerning your point 5, I didn't know about that type inference is better with State[S, A] I just used the same order of the tuple  S => (A, S), it blended less my mind.

Comment: @Shodz Re "the constraint on upper-bound does not allows to use class with a single type like class BoxMonad[A](box: A)" - not only does it allow that, it *forces* you to give it a type constructor with a single type hole; That's why we had to bind the type parameter `S` in `State[S, A]` with the type-lambda.

Comment: @Shodz " I get a cyclic reference" - yes, and there is a good reason why this happens. By attempting to tie the `State` with the monad definition into a single object, you're essentially setting up [this game](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/870/435/548) for yourself. I've added a section in the answer explaining why this happens.

Comment: @Shodz " I didn't know about that type inference is better with State[S, A]" - It's about how the compiler attempts to split up type-level expressions into type-constructors and arguments. For ex., if one sees only `Foo[A, B]`, then it could be interpreted as an application of a single-parameter type constructor in many different ways, for example: `([X] =>> Foo[X, B])[A]`, or `([X] =>> Foo[A, X])[B]`, or even `([X] => Foo[A, B])[Int]`. But the compiler won't try all of them. Instead, will try only `([X] =>> Foo[A, X])[B]`, and rely on the convention that the last arg is what's abstracted over